# How to give the same results of accuracy score after the using cross validation?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to use cross validation for my dataset in Python 3. However, every time I run the code I get the different result of evaluation score. What if I want the same result.

```
lr = linear_model.LogisticRegression()
rf = ensemble.RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 5, criterion = 'entropy')
folds = StratifiedKFold(n_splits = 10, shuffle = True, random_state=None)

lr_scoresa = cross_val_score(lr, X, Y, scoring ='accuracy', cv = folds)
rf_scoresa = cross_val_score(rf, X, Y, scoring ='accuracy', cv = folds)
rf_scoresf = cross_val_score(rf, X, Y, scoring ='f1', cv = folds)

print(np.mean(rf_scoresa),np.mean(rf_scoresf))
print(np.mean(lr_scoresa))
```

Comment: Isn't this related to the fact that you are using `RandomForestClasifier` which is exactly that - **random**? I would not expect the same results every time...

Comment: I just add one of my models - Random Forests. However, even with Logistic Regression, the result would change. So I think the problem could be on the random folds split. How can I get all same fold splits ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem relates to the randomness of both `RandomForestClassifier` and `StratifiedKFold`. I suggest you change the last parameter `random_state` to some int (e.g. `1`). [Documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html) suggests that in other cases the behaviour is indeed random:

```
If `None`, the random number generator is the `RandomState` instance used by `np.random`. Used when `shuffle == True`.
```

The crucial line of code should look like this:

`folds = StratifiedKFold(n_splits = 10, shuffle = True, random_state=1)`

Answer (score 0):

```
folds = StratifiedKFold(n_splits = 10, shuffle = True, random_state=1)
```

does not lead to the same accuracy scores. It just leads to the same folds of data. I believe that the best solution is to use a number for the random state within each classifier too.

```
rf_scoresf = cross_val_score(rf, X, Y, scoring ='f1', cv = folds, randomstate = 42)
```